# Where does this question belong?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

This question just came up

[Is Webmedcentral a reputable scientific publisher?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/6807/389)

We certainly have the expertise to answer this question but it seems to be more appropriate for academia.stackexchange. Any thoughts?

Comment: I did think about migrating to Academia but thought I'd wait to see if off topic votes came in first.  Although if we believe that we have the expertise to answer the question here then we should do - [see this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Comment: Definitively guys at academia.se could help.

Answer (score 1):

Academia.SE generally allows questions about specific publishers, so it would be on-topic for them. Though I personally would not migrate unless we decide that we don't want this type of question at all.

As it is written, I think the question is not constructive, but it could be easily changed to avoid that problem. We can't actually answer he question in which journal someone should publish, but we can e.g. answer whether it is a known and reputable publisher, or possibly a predatory open access publisher.

I'm undecided on whether we should allow these questions, so I'll wait for some community input. But this example doesn't look that good, the only answer doesn't really answer anything, so I'm not sure if we are the right site for this kind of question.